# angular, vhost and jboss

Tags: angular, virtualhost

I've packaged my angular v4 app in a war : my-app.war.
This war is served by jboss

This app should then be accessible with http://myDomain/my-app/

I've set a Vhost to point on my app when I call http://myDomain/ like that :

```
<Location "/">
  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/my-app/
</Location>
```

So when I call http://myDomain/, I can access to my app, but if I want to access to a specific route, i get a 404 error (like http://myDomain/home)

I can access to http://myDomain/home by navigating in my angular app tho, but not able to access it directly (like with a favorite or so)

Any idea about how to do?

**Edit** :
My vhost is now :

```
<Location "/">
  RewriteEngine On
  # If an existing asset or directory is requested go to it as it is
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -f [OR]
  RewriteCond %{DOCUMENT_ROOT}%{REQUEST_URI} -d
  RewriteRule ^ - [L]

  # If the requested resource doesn't exist, use index.html
  RewriteRule ^ /index.html

  ProxyPass http://127.0.0.1:8080/my-app/
</Location>
```

When I try to access http://myDomain/ I only got "Loading" displayed, the app doesn't load cause in console I got all the *.bundle.js in 404. It tries to load from http://myDomain/*.bundle.js although it should tries on http://myDomain/my-app/*.bundle.js, but don't know how to fix that

When I try to call http://myDomain/home I get a 500 error

Comment: Have you configured either your proxy, or your app, to serve anything on /home? If not, why would it serve anything on that path. You need to configure one of them to serve index.html for **all** routes of your app. See https://angular.io/guide/deployment#routed-apps-must-fallback-to-indexhtml

Comment: That's the point of my question, how can I do that? I'll not list every existing route in my vhost I guess there's something handy?

Comment: See the link I posted in my comment. If you want to do it in your app, just use a servlet filter intercepting all requests, and fowarding to index.html for all paths except, for example, the ones starting with /images, /api, etc.

Comment: Yes ok but this route  http://myDomain/home do exist in my app, it leads to somewhere, i don't want a fallback, I want to be able to access it directly. Like for example  http://myDomain/article/2, I don't want to be redirected to index, I want to display the article page

Comment: I never said redirect. I said forward. So, you fo do /article/2, the browser gets, **at this addess** a response containing the index.html page, so the angular app starts, sees that the address is /article/2, and thus navigates to the corresponding route. Why don't you even trust the official angular documentation I linked to?

Comment: Ah sorry then I missunderstood your answer. I'm new to angular and know nothing about vhost.
I've edited my question with my actual vhost